# Using rename tool to remove a character that is before an uppercase letter

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, rename

I made a mistake in my script and replaced all spaces with 's' instead of underscore. I would like to undo this change. I have names like:

```
BatmansBegins
FightsClub
ThesDeparted
TouchsOfsEvil
```

I would like to name this to

```
Batman_Begins
Fight_Club
The_Departed
Touch_Of_Evil
```

I have this command at the moment but it replaces the 's' and the uppercase letter that follows it

```
rename -n 's/s[A-Z]/_/g'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to capture uppercase letter and use a back-reference in replacement.  So use it as:

```
rename -n 's/s([A-Z])/_$1/g' *s[A-Z]*
```

Another option is to use positive lookahead in your regex:

```
rename -n 's/s(?=[A-Z])/_/g' *s[A-Z]*
```

`(?=[A-Z])` is positive lookahead that asserts presence of an uppercase letter after matching `s`.

PS: There are quite a few variants of `rename` tool and it appears that you're using popular perl based `rename` utility and this answer is also based on that.

Comment: Maybe note that there is an imperial cubic lightyear of different `rename` tools. The "canonical" one is a popular Perl tool; that is apparently what this answer presupposes.

Comment: `*s[A-Z]*` matchs `file.sh`, too.

Comment: It is same as what OP is using i.e. perl based `rename` tool.

Comment: @Cyrus: At least on my OSX filesystem `*s[A-Z]*` doesn't match `file.sh`

Comment: @anubhava: I found my bug. `LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"` is the problem. It works fine if I switch to `LC_COLLATE="C"`. Thank you.